# How to hide Thunderbird's name from remote IMAP-server?

Tags: thunderbird, imap, thunderbird-addon

Apparently, IMAP-protocol has its own version of `User-Agent` and Thunderbird, for example, proudly identifies itself as such -- and also supplies its version -- every time it logs-in. For example, here is, what my IMAP-server logs:

```
Dec 29 21:27:49 narawntapu imap[24943]: client id: "name" "Thunderbird" "version" "52.5.0"
```

Is there any way to either disable the header completely or overwrite the string? Firefox has an undocumented setting to explicitly change `User-Agent`, and there are also add-ons, which allow you to set different strings for different sites, etc.

Is there anything like it for Thunderbird?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have Thunderbird installed at the moment, so I can't test, but according to [this page](https://www.ghacks.net/2012/09/08/hide-the-user-agent-when-sending-emails-with-thunderbird/), you can change the user agent by adding a new preference in about:config, called "general.useragent.override". If you leave it blank, you will send a blank user agent.